# 'QgsProcessingProvider' object has no attribute

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, error

I'm trying to do a simple conversion of a polygon to vertices and I get an error that says:

> AttributeError: 'QgsProcessingProvider' object has no attribute
>   'isSupportedOutputValue'  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmDialog.py",
>   line 180, in runAlgorithm
>
> parameters = self.getParameterValues()   File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmDialog.py",
>   line 168, in getParameterValues ok, error =
>   self.algorithm().provider().isSupportedOutputValue(value, param,
>   context) AttributeError: 'QgsProcessingProvider' object has no
>   attribute 'isSupportedOutputValue'

**Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.6.0-Noosa Noosa, 58734527ab**

Does anyone have an idea on what's causing this issue?